# Images in android app getting a weird background gradient

Tags: android, image

I decided to run the same exact app one day and figured that images are getting these weird black gradient-like background instead of transparency. Seems like the images are not being rendered correctly.

The image is transparent. And it seems that the background of the image is being replaced by this error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Here is the xml layout file:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:stretchColumns="2" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:text="@string/VincentiDesc2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:maxLines="100"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yes_button"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_default_holo_light"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/yes_button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/no_button"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_default_holo_light"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/no_button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:text="@string/VincentiNoteDesc2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="normal" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:maxLines="100"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and the Fragment

```
public class Description2Fragment extends SherlockFragment {
    OnNextPressedListener mListener;
    View nobutton;
    View yesbutton;

    //update Personal Info variables

private long PIid;
public PersonalInfo newPI;
private PersonalInfoDataSource datasource;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_description2, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    nobutton = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.no_button);
    nobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datasource = new PersonalInfoDataSource(getActivity());
            datasource.open();

            List<PersonalInfo> l = datasource.getAllPersonalInfos();
            if(l==null) {
                newPI = datasource.createPersonalInfo("", "", "", "", "", false,"","","","");
            } else if (l.size()==0) {
                newPI = datasource.createPersonalInfo("", "", "", "", "", false,"","","","");
            } else {
                newPI = l.get(0);
            }

            datasource.updatePersonalInfoStat(newPI.getId(), false);

            datasource.close();
            mListener.nextPressed(1);

        }
    });

    yesbutton = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yes_button);
    yesbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            //update Stat to 1 = TRUE
            datasource = new PersonalInfoDataSource(getActivity());
            datasource.open();

            List<PersonalInfo> l = datasource.getAllPersonalInfos();
            if(l==null) {
                newPI = datasource.createPersonalInfo("", "", "", "", "", false,"","","","");
            } else if (l.size()==0) {
                newPI = datasource.createPersonalInfo("", "", "", "", "", false,"","","","");
            } else {
                newPI = l.get(0);
            }

            datasource.updatePersonalInfoStat(newPI.getId(), true);

            datasource.close();
            mListener.nextPressed(1);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please put some code or xml layout file for same?

Comment: Placed xml layout file and fragment in an edit! Sorry about that! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1:** Upon implementing ActionBarSherlock & running your layout (subbing the images for the stock IC launcher icons), and putting in a background color for visibility, I get this:
[image].

You can clearly see the ABS transparent line to the right of the android icons.

So without seeing any issue in your layout, I'd check your images themselves. Were they recently resaved? Are you certain your ActionBarSherlock iconset hasn't been removed at all? Make sure that ABS icon exists for all of your appropriate resolutions in your drawable-*res* folders.

Comment: Placed xml layout file and fragment in an edit! Sorry about that! Thanks for your help